# pip version error with installed package

Tags: python, heroku, pip

I'm attempting to install a package I recently create into a Heroku app. It seems that Heroku uses an older version of pip which prevents my package from installing correctly. I repeated the process with [repl.it](https://repl.it) to see what happens and here is what I get:

```
Repl.it: Installing fresh packages
Repl.it: zoho_crm

Collecting zoho_crm
  Downloading
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8e/73/a1464dd121fec9579c724de6b9b3243ea733fb85d441b928ff467ec1328f/zoho_crm-0.5.tar.gz 
Building wheels for collected packages: zoho-crm
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for zoho-crm: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for zoho-crm: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /home/runner/.cache/pip/wheels/46/66/f9/c9604984f6670461c451dd9431105760405d06c658d3b44f01
Successfully built zoho-crm
Installing collected packages: zoho-crm
Successfully installed zoho-crm-0.5
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.


Repl.it: package installation success

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zoho_crm'
```

Line 1 of my code (the only line) is `import zoho_crm`

This is also the same error I get in Heroku.

I have no problems updating pip on my local machine, but the update with these cloud services seems to update but doesn't stick.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That version warning is only warning and can be safely ignored now. Your problem has nothing to do with `pip`, the problem is caused by the broken package `zoho_crm` — it doesn't contain anything installable, neither python modules nor packages.

Comment: It seems I followed an incomplete tutorial on how to create a package. I installed it locally via pip so I was never aware the package was broken. Thank you!

Comment: You have to use either `py_modules=['some']` (to install `some.py`) or `packages=['some']` (to install `some/*.py`). You have to list all subpackages (`packages=['some', 'some.sub1', 'some.sub2']`); to avoid that use `packages=find_packages()`.